# Meaning/Origin of word "Nixie"

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, obscure-terms

In the area of which I live, there is a certain word we use to describe somebody that is naughty, or bad, in a joking/lighthearted manner. I do not know how to spell the word, and every attempt to find it on Google led to no accurate results.

The word sounds like 'Nixee' with a hard e at the end. It might be spelled Nixy or Nixie.

We live in the middle of Pennsylvania Dutch and Amish country. The word is exceedingly common around these parts and was interested in the history.

My question is what is the history of the word 'Nixy' and is it commonplace among other parts of the United States?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Water_Nixie.   https://www.etymonline.com/word/nixie#etymonline_v_6977

Comment: This looks to me like a derivative of Ger. *Taugenichts* = "good-for-nothing, slacker, scapegrace, ne'er-do-well". *-nichtse* would be the ordinary plural, but who knows what might happen in a mixed-language region?

Comment: Spent most of my 69 years in the US Midwest, and the term is not familiar to me.  ("Nixie tube", however, brings fond memories.)

Comment: I've lived all across the USA, and have never heard "nyxie" outside of mythology.

Comment: @StoneyB:  I think you're on to something there, because in informal German, "nichts" becomes "nix."

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty of normalising the spelling of the word to _nixie_, since the original spelling made it look more like an Internet startup company.

Comment: @StoneyB Your intuition derived from your expertise is enough to make a man feel small! You guessed this off the bat, and it’s confirmed by every source I found. I’m a little ashamed to only have noticed your comment after having written my answer! Reading it first would have saved me a lot of time. And Wordster saw it too.... I wish I could trade some of my Googling skills for your language skills.

Comment: It needs to be observed that "nixie" is a fairly obvious candidate for a neologism (variation of "pixie", et al) and so it's not unlikely that the word has been invented several times with different origins.

Comment: @DanBron You did the legwork; and I'd completely forgotten *nichtsnutz*, which was an epithet my father was very fond of. I don't know where he got it; he was from Tennessee, but like most of his generation he mingled with a lot of furriners from the North in the Army. And he was of German Jewish extraction, so it may have been a familyism.

Comment: Given that “nix” is the Germanic version of “naught”, it is not surprising that “nixie” is the Germanic version of “naughty”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### A good-for-nothing answer

All sources I could find suggest ***nixie*** (variously spelled) comes from German, which accounts for its concentration in Pennsylvania and among or around Pennsylvania Dutch speakers.  It is essentially unknown to American speakers outside that community¹.

The most detailed and plausible explanation I found, though the source is far from a linguistic reference, is *[The Pennsylvania Dutch Alphabet](http://pelicanpub.com/proddetail.php?prod=9781589804968#.W4B_5aQpDDs)*, by Chet Williamson (first published September 15th 2007 by Pelican Publishing Company).

Here’s the page that caught my eye, the entry for `N`:

[image: Screenshot from *The Pennsylvania Dutch Alphabet* entry `N`, quoted below, with an illustration of a grandma chiding a naughty grandson]

Transcription:

> **ℕ** is for **nixnootz**
> A rascally child
> Who gets into trouble
> And runs around wild!
>
> The Pennsylvania Dutch are very loving to their children, but you’ll often hear parents telling their little ***nixnootzes*** (or ***nichts-nutzes***), “don’t be so ***nixie***!”

So the theory held out here is that *nixie*, as a noun or adjective effectively synonymous with *naughty*, is a shortened form of  *nixnootz*, **derived from German *nichts-nutzes***, which translates to (per [dict.cc](https://m.dict.cc/german-english/nichts+nutzen.html)):

> nichts nutzen | nutzte nichts/nichts nutzte | nichts genutzt (VERB):
>
> jdm. nichts nutzen
> **to be of no benefit to sb**.
>
> nichts nutzen
> **to be of no use**
> to be to no avail
> to avail to nothing

ie, a good-for-nothing, someone whose idle hands look like ideal real estate for the Devil’s next workshop.

As I said, this is hardly a scholarly work of linguistics, but the word’s inclusion in this particular primer does suggest (a) the work is unique or particular to Pennsylvania Dutch country and (b) it would be familiar to young children of that community (I believe such books are usually targeted at children around 4-5 years old).

#### Nicht!

However, in search of a more scholarly source to bolster this theory, I also found some discussion of this word in an episode of the podcast *A Way with Words* called “[Doppick and Nixie](https://www.waywordradio.org/doppick-and-nixie/)”, recorded October 20, 2010.

At the outset, a caller introduces herself as a veterinarian who moved to [Selinsgrove, PA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinsgrove,_Pennsylvania) (in central PA) 20 years prior to calling (so the period she encountered the words below must have been between 1990 and 2010).

She called in to ask about a few words she’d encountered among the local population which were novel to her:

- *doppick* (clumsy),
- *nixie* (naughty), and
- *dressed* (in this usage meaning neutered / spayed for pets)

The host says of *nixie* (timestamp about 2:53 to 3:33 in the audio):

> This is a little more of a stretch, but I’m betting this also comes from German, from the German word ***nicht***, which means *no*.
> That’s when you have a cat or a child doing something they shouldn’t do, you say *no! no! no!* or *nicht! nicht! nicht!*. And it’s directly related to *nix* in English.

The host is somewhat of an expert of English and etymology (the point of the call-in show), but here he explicitly notes he’s speculating.

However, the caller did also present *doppic* as sourced from the same local speakers, and by most accounts this indeed a [direct borrowing from German](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/doplic).

In any case, his theory that it derives from *nicht* aligns very well with the *nichts-nutzes* account from *The Pennsylvania Dutch Alphabet* given above.

#### Enter if you DARE

That said, the host of the podcast is still speculating in his answer (and as [@Janus Bahs Jacquet points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461546/meaning-origin-of-word-nixie/461667#comment1113491_461667) in the comments, even taken at face value, it still demonstrates some unfamiliarity with German), so I wanted to find a more professional reference.

The go-to work for such questions is the  *Dictionary of American Regional English*, aka *DARE*, which does have an entry for [*nixie*](https://www.daredictionary.com/view/dare/ID_00040641)².

Unfortunately, it is of no help in this particular case, as the glosses are only tangentially relevant:

> ***nixie*** *n*
> The young of the chipping sparrow. [...]
> NEng [...]. nixie *adv*
> Also sp nixy =nix *adv*
> 1.. *nix* *adv* [Ger *nichts* nothing] 1 No; definitely not! chiefly Nth See Map
> Cf *nit* *adv*, *nixie* *adv*.

---

¹ <sub>This statement is anecdotal based on my experience as a native speaker of AmE (NYC based), as well as the comments of others in this and similar topics around the web, and the fact that I had to search hard to find sites which even discussed this word, let alone give an account of its origins.</sub>

<sub>On top of that, none of the several  dictionaries I checked using [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=Nixie&ls=a) listed this sense of the word. Most redirected to straight *nix*, and the rest listed unrelated senses (muses, water sprites, illegibly addressed mail, etc).</sub>

<sub>In the name of scholarship, however, I did a search in both the *Corpus of Contemporary English* ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=68257933)) and [Google nGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Nixie%2C%20nix&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CNixie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BNixie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnixie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNIXIE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnix%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BNix%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnix%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNIX%3B%2Cc0), and both show *nixie* (so spelled) is virtually unused in [written] English, particularly not contemporary [written] English, and when it is, it’s used in an unrelated sense (*Nixie tubes* mostly, then water sprites, then a proper noun / given name *Nixie*).</sub>

²  <sub>Sadly, despite coveting it for years, I don’t have access to this work, but user [@njuffa  graciously provided the contents](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461546/meaning-origin-of-word-nix-e/461667#comment1113472_461667) of the entry for us in the comments.</sub>

Comment: This answer is very good. This is the reference you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_German_language Deitsch, Pennsylvania Deitsch, Pennsilfaanisch Deitsch aka Pennsylvania Dutch. And believe it or not, the towns of Blueball, Intercourse and Paradise are all in Lancaster County, where many Pennsylvania Dutch speakers [an old German dialect] live.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks! What do you suggest I do with that reference?

Comment: The DARE entries are only mildly relevant: **nixie** n The young of the **chipping sparrow.** [...] **NEng** [...]. **nixie** adv Also sp *nixy* **=nix** adv **1.**. **nix** adv [Ger *nichts* nothing] **1** No; definitely not! **chiefly Nth** See Map Cf **nit** adv, **nixie** adv.

Comment: Incorporate it into your answer: old order Mennonite and old order Amish still speak Pennsylvania Dutch. I have been there; it's amazing. The Amish and Mennonites live elsewhere too but Lancaster County is the main  place for it.

Comment: @Lambie I kind of took it as a given that my readers (and of course OP, who lives along those people) are aware of Pennsylvania Dutch as a language. Didn’t think I needed to call that out explicitly?

Comment: @njuffa Wonderful! Thanks for looking it up for us. I’ll edit that in.

Comment: Not everyone is a native English speaker. Those from outside the English-speaking world may not know it. Do as you like. I'm easy unlike some around here. :)

Comment: The guy on the podcast is of course right that this is related to German negatives, but it’s clear he doesn’t speak any German himself. _Nicht_ means ‘not’, and you wouldn’t say “Nicht! Nicht! Nicht!” to a German-speaking miscreant any more than you’d say “Not! Not! Not!” to its English cousin. If anything, you’d say “Nein!” or “No!”. So that particular (folk) etymology is bunkum. _Nichts_ is a much more likely origin than _nicht_, having the additional benefit, as Wordster points out in his comment to the question, of very commonly becoming _nix_ in colloquial German.

Comment: I thought it a splendid answer. Thank you for writing up such an entertaining and enlightening answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh wow! I didn’t even realize there was a bounty on this Q. Thank you for the award! Would that only there were more interesting Qs like this that would give us opportunities to research and write up interesting answers.